# Understanding Quantum point contact

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Am I correct in saying that quantum contact is  : for a quantum heterostructure, by applying a voltage between two needle shaped split gate, it would deplete the electrons beneath it, therefore producing a potential trap that confines electron in the transverse direction.  The width and the height of the potential constriction can be controlled by changing the voltage between the split gates, is that right? [image]

Comment: Questions like this can be... disappointing to say the least. Especially when the answer is a simple "yes".

Comment: @Jimmy360  I don't quite understand why changing the gate voltage can change the width of the constriction though

Comment: I am not saying that the answer is yes. I don't know.